# Remove a class after image is loaded

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, bootstrap-5, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to find a simple way using JS to implement Boostrap 5 placeholder to lazy each image that I load.

Bootstrap 5 has a class named `placeholder` that adds a visual “loading card” to a component and I want to use this class until an image is completed load. After that, the class must be excluded and the "loading card" must go away. Important: I will have more de than one image, so the loading card must be exclude for each image separately.

I'm struggling to find information on forums for that reason I'm looking for some help here.

[Here bootstrap component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye5DA.png).

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` element seems to have no event "onloaded" or so. The following function can be used to load the image source with Javascript code and remove the `placeholder` class once this is completed.

```js
async function load(img) {
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(await (await fetch(img.getAttribute("xsrc"))).blob());
  img.classList.remove("placeholder");
}
```

```css
.placeholder { border: solid 5px black; }
```

```html
<body onload="load(document.querySelector('img'))">
  <img width="100" height="100" class="placeholder" xsrc="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjy1a31kVAiCn_hJAWq34vNkEHuXwBWbuL00Eakf4g=k-s48"/>
</body>
```